# flutter web : just audio exception : PlatformException(abort, Loading interrupted, null, null)

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am getting PlatformException only in web when changing the audio url from one to another.Everything works fine in android and IOS.Issue is only in web.

```
just_audio: ^0.9.35
```

this is the version og plugin used.

```
    Error: PlatformException(abort, Loading interrupted, null, null)
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 1247:7                                    checkInterruption
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 1358:11                                   setPlatform
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 641:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
Error: PlatformException(error, Platform player 510aeb46-afa2-42f6-a4e3-5728ef8fafad already exists, null, null)
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49         throw_
packages/just_audio_web/just_audio_web.dart 22:7                                     init
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                   runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                   _async
packages/just_audio_web/just_audio_web.dart 20:35                                    init
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 1341:54                                          setPlatform
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                   runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                   _async
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 1328:44                                          setPlatform
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 1452:17                                          [_setPlatformActive]
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 785:20                                           load
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                   runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                   _async
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 773:25                                           load
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 756:24                                           setAudioSource
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                   runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                   _async
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 738:35                                           setAudioSource
packages/just_audio/just_audio.dart 669:7                                            setUrl
```

Code sample is given below.

```
 setPlayer(String url) async {
    try {
      _selectedMood = moodBloc.state.selectedMood;
      await _stopPlayer();
      await _player.setVolume(_getVolumeValue(state.volume));
      await _player.setUrl(url);
      _subscribeToStream();
    } catch (e) {
      print('set player error====e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: If it's reporting that the player already exists, that would indicate a bug in the plugin. You'll need to report it on GitHub so that it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:just_audio/just_audio.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: playSound1,
              child: const Text("Play sound 1"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: playSound2,
              child: const Text("Play sound 2"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> playSound1() async {
    if (player.playing) {
      await player.stop();
    }
    await player.setUrl(
      "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/DDR_assets/Kangaroo_MusiQue_-_The_Neverwritten_Role_Playing_Game.mp3",
    );
    await player.play();
    await player.stop();
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  Future<void> playSound2() async {
    if (player.playing) {
      await player.stop();
    }
    await player.setUrl(
      "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/DDR_assets/Sevish_-__nbsp_.mp3",
    );
    await player.play();
    await player.stop();
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you immadiatly stopping after calling play method?

Comment: To handle this: Error: AbortError: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.

Comment: You cannot play multiple songs at the moment in the same instance. 
It is possible with multiple instances.

Comment: thank you @Dharam. I was not doing await before playing second url.works fine now.